# How do I reliably access my music library in Google Play music from my car's bluetooth system

Tags: samsung, bluetooth, google-play-music

i have a Samsung Galaxy S6 and 2015 Mazda. In general, access my music via bluetooth in my car works much better when I disable Google PLay Music and only use the native music app. However, I would prefer to use Google Play Music simply because when I purchase music from the app and download them to the phone, they are not available to the native app (or any app other than Google Play music...argh!)

So, I am using Tasker to successfully automatically play Google Play Music when it connects to the car's bluetooth, and that works very well. And the music does play.

However, and this is my specific problem, sometimes I cannot access the library screen on my cars bluetooth system, where I choose the artist, track, playlist, album, etc.

Specifically, when I try to select the library icon, it says: "unable to view the content of the connected device."

Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Are you using Android Auto? That is the only way I have been able to access anything other then Pause/Play and Previous & Next track via Bluetooth, I have no access to a library and I am using a 2018 Hyundai Sonata (but the Android Auto is awesome!). Guess I am confused that this is even a possibility...

Comment: Is your phone plugged in by USB as well? Usually choosing a track from the car is only available for plugging in USB storage to the car, not for Bluetooth (except Android Auto, as acejavelin says).

Comment: I've answered my own question. Things are working well. Basically, to get a Mazda 2015 Bluetooth to work well with a Samsung Galaxy S6 i did the following:

1. used Tasker to set the phone up such that the moment the phone is connected to the car's bluetooh Google PLay is launched

2. To get it working, sometimes you have to click "forward" and then "play" on the car's bluetooth screen"

3. There are times when the car's bluetooth will not read the phone's library. This necessitates turning the phone's bluetooth off and then on again. It seems to work well then.

Comment: You should write an answer then and mark it accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Tasker to set the phone up such that the moment the phone is connected to the car's bluetooth, Google Play is launched and a song is played. Then, you'll be able to control the phone's music in Google Play through the car's head unit.